# How can I prove the following problem is NP?

Tags: complexity-theory, np-hard, np, p-vs-np

Because of the covid-19 pandemic, our firm works semi-remote working. We want to that:

1. Every day 2/5 of staff should be in the office.
2. Everyone should go to the office 2 times a week.
3. Teams want to go to the office together. But teams are not very strict. Some people are in 2 teams. So there may be no best solution for everyone.
4. Some people should be in the office some specific day of the week.

I believe that the problem is NP-hard because I can't check if some scheduling is the best scheduling in polynomial time.

But I am not sure. Is it NP-hard, NP-complete, or just a P? How can it be proven without any doubt?

Comment: It can be proven by either giving a polynomial-time algorithm for the problem or by describing a polynomial-time reduction from an NP-hard problem to it. But before you can do either one, you should formalize the problem. What is the input and what is the output?

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I can formalize the problem academically, but I can be more specific if it helps.

Comment: Formalizing is a form of making the question precise.  If you can't do that, then it's premature to ask whether it is NP-complete or not; that's a first step towards that.  Your requirement #3 is pretty vague and handwavy.  We need precise, objectively evaluable criteria to determine whether a particular candidate solution is correct or not.  Are you asking how to solve this in practice, or are you asking about its theoretical complexity?